# Recursive bubble sort TLE in java

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have written code to do bubble sort recursive. But I am getting Time limit exceeded. Can anyone help me to figure out why?

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr, int index, int j){
        if (index == arr.length) return;
        if (j == arr.length-1) return;
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;
        }
        bubbleSort(arr, index, j+1);
        //print(arr);
        bubbleSort(arr, index+1, 0);
    }
```

`Function calling: bubbleSort(arr, 0, 0);`

Comment: Which system is producing that "time limit exceeded"? Are you by any chance submitting this on a code challenge site?

Comment: @trincot Yes checking on code challenging site

Comment: So what has debugging (setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, stepping...) given?

Comment: Off-topic (probably), but, could you, please, include a link to the problem's page at the code challenge / practice site?

Comment: I presume this is either homework or an academic exercise of some sort (pun intended) since you are taking an inefficient sort and making it more inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have *two* recursive calls per function execution context, but just one. Otherwise the number of recursive calls we be exponential O(2), while you only need O(n²) calls of `bubbleSort`.

Use an `if` condition to decide which of the two recursive calls you need:

```
    if (j < arr.length - 2) {
        bubbleSort(arr,index,j+1);
    } else {
        bubbleSort(arr,index+1,0);
    }
```

You can even make the condition a bit stricter, because in each phase of bubble sort, the sorted partition at the end of the array grows:

```
    if (j < arr.length - 2 - index) {
```

You can also remove the stop condition on `j`.

Comment: Okay, so in any problem we shouldn't use two or more recursive call. We should use condition to call the desired recursion. Please clarify me. It's like tips for the recursion

Comment: This is completely dependent on the problem that is being solved. For some problems, you **do** need multiple recursive calls. But realise that this **doubles** the number of executions at each level of the recursion tree. For bubble sort this is not what you want.

Comment: public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr,int index,int j){
        if(index==arr.length-1) return;
        if(j<arr.length-1){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
            bubbleSort(arr, index, j+1);
        }else{
            bubbleSort(arr, index+1, 0);
        }
    }
Is this a correct logic I have coded it again?

Comment: A bit hard to read in comments, but yes, that looks fine. Just realise that recursion *adds* stack space usage. Really not necessary here.